In a PDF document, how can I "split" a TJ operator into multiple Tj/Td that are completely equivalent?
A related question here: (TJ and Td offset difference) has an answer which explains how to do the opposite (turn Tjs and Tds into an equivalent TJ). From this I can deduce fairly trivially how to do it the other way round, but this naive approach has the problem that other (seemingly unrelated) bits of text also get shifted when I do this (in a manner I don't exactly understand).
A caveat in the answer the the question linked above points out that "even then the two forms are not identical because the text line matrix at the end differs" which is probably the cause of these seemingly random jumps in seemingly unrelated places.
I'm a PDF noob and not entirely sure what exactly a "text line" (or text line matrix) is.
I'm using PDFBox, in particular PdfContentStreamEditor (here) so an answer using that toolset would be especially great, but a good general "how to" would certainly get me a long way towards it.
Thanks in advance.

See 9.4 of the PDF Spec: https://pdfa.org/resource/iso-32000-pdf/

As John Whitington pointed out in a comment, the details of PDF text showing are explained in the PDF spec ISO 32000-2 the current version of which can be retrieved for free from the PDF Association at https://pdfa.org/resource/iso-32000-pdf/
The relevant details:

There are two matrix variables during the processing of a text object that define where in text space the text is drawn. These variables hold the text matrix Tm and the text line matrix Tlm.
The text matrix defines how the drawing instructions in a font file (after normalization) shall be transformed into text space.
The text line matrix is the last value of the text matrix read and set by certain instructions. The name is most senseful if these instructions are used to go to the next line (like "set Tm and Tlm to the previous Tlm combined with a move down by a line height). But those instructions can also be used to move to the next cell in a table or simply a bit to the side, and then the name is not that sensible anymore.
At the beginning of a text object, both these matrices are set to the identity matrix. In particular, the origin of a glyph drawn now would be drawn at the origin of text space.
The operator Tm sets both the text matrix and the text line matrix to its matrix parameter.
The operators Td and TD apply a translation according to their parameters to the text line matrix and set both the text matrix and the text line matrix to this new value.
The operator T* applies a translation downwards by the current text leading value to the text line matrix and sets both the text matrix and the text line matrix to this new value.
The operators Tj and TJ only forward the text matrix to the next position after the text they draw.
The operators ' and " first change the text matrix and text line matrix like T* and then forward the text matrix like Tj.

Concerning your question

how can I "split" a TJ operator into multiple Tj/Td that are completely equivalent?

you, therefore, in general cannot faithfully replace a TJ by an equivalent sequence of Tj and Td instructions: The former only changes the text matrix (so that afterwards the text line matrix has not moved) while the latter changes both the text line matrix and the text matrix. And you cannot set the text line matrix to its former value without also changing the text matrix.
What you can do, though, is remember the most recent value of the text line matrix. After you then replaced a TJ by Tjs and Tds, you continue processing the next instructions (maybe even replacing other TJs by Tjs and Tds), and as soon as you encounter an instruction that uses the text line matrix, you insert right before it a Tm that sets the text line matrix to the remembered value (alternatively: Undo all the effects of your replacement Tds with a Td with the negative sum of all your changes). If you encounter a Tm, though, you can stop as the Tm sets both text matrix and text line matrix absolutely.
For example, consider you have a text object like this:
BT
30 600 Td
[(A) 34 (B) -567 (C)] TJ
0 -15 Td
[(D) -1500 (E)] TJ
(FGH) Tj
0 -15 TD
[(I) 17 (J)] TD
(K) '
ET

You can transform it like this:

BT - text line matrix is Identity
BT


30 600 Td - text line matrix is Identity translated by (30, 600)
30 600 Td


[(A) 34 (B) -567 (C)] TJ - replace; this changes the text line matrix
(A) Tj
a 0 Td
(B) Tj
b 0 Td
(C) Tj


0 -15 Td - this uses the text line matrix, so first set the text line matrix to the remembered value or alternatively undo all the Tds you added:
1 0 0 1 30 600 Tm
0 -15 Td

or
-a-b 0 Td
0 -15 Td

The text line matrix now is the identity translated by (30, 585).
[(D) -1500 (E)] TJ - replace
(D) Tj
c 0 Td
(E) Tj


(FGH) Tj - copy as is
(FGH) Tj


0 -15 TD - fix text line matrix
1 0 0 1 30 585 Tm
0 -15 TD

or
-c 0 Td
0 -15 TD

The text line matrix now is the identity translated by (30, 570).
[(I) 17 (J)] TD - replace
(I) Tj
d 0 Td
(J) Tj


(K) ' - fix
1 0 0 1 30 570 Tm
(K) '

or
-d 0 Td
(K) '

The text line matrix now is the identity translated by (30, 565).
ET
ET




An alternative would be to use character spacing: draw the last glyph of a string separately, before it set the character spacing to include all extra space, and after it reset the character spacing to the former value.

Wow, as you said in your comment on the original question, it's decidedly non-trivial. The character spacing hack might be the way to go, it's definitely simpler (conceptually at least). Thanks for the response. Working on s different task at the moment but I'll return to it later.
